# Error 404 java web jsp

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp

Hola me encontre con dicho error al momento de querer "`redireccionar`" mi `controlador`, el problema es que no entiendo porque me sale ese error, probe con todo

Codigo donde tengo boton "crear"

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="calculo.do">
                    <fieldset>

                        <!-- Form Name -->
                        <legend class="text-center">Calculo NOTAS </legend>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="codigo">Codigo</label>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="codigo" value="${obj1.dni}" name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="Codigo Cliente" class="form-control input-md"></br>
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nombre" value="${obj1.nombres}" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre Cliente" class="form-control input-md"></br>
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="apellido">Apellido</label>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="apellido" value="${obj1.apellidos}" name="apellido" type="text" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nota1">NOTA 1</label>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nota1" value="${obj1.nota1}" name="nota1" type="text" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nota2">NOTA 2</label>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nota2" value="${obj1.nota2}" name="nota2" type="text" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nota3">NOTA 3</label>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nota3" value="${obj1.nota3}" name="nota3" type="text" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Button (Double) -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <button id="action" value="Crear" name="action" class="btn btn-success">Crear</button>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/ParcialCorte1/trabajadores.do" role="button">Regresar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Aquí es donde quiero redireccionar mi `controlador` llamado "calculo"

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("Administrador/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Adjunto imagen del orden de mis carpetas dentro de administrador tengo index.jsp pero siempre me devuelve error 404 que podria ser el error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe recalcar que cuando tenia el `jsp` en la raiz me funcionaba bien, solo fue cambiarlo y empezo a fallar

Answer (score 0):

El Servlet, Calculo se registró en el ServletContext mapeado en la ruta del contexto diferente a la ruta a tu jsp Administrador/index.jsp se refiere a otro contexto. Por ello  responde con 404.

Puedes obtener la refencia al otro contexto usando algo asi :

```
 ServletContext contexto2 = request.getServletContext().getContext("/Administrador/index.jsp");
```

ahora que ya estas en ese contexto puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
contexto2.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Recuerda que el nombre de ruta siempre debe comenzar con un / y se interpreta como relativo a la raíz del contexto actual.